# How to find document from object property in array property in model

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have two models:

**User:**

```
{ 
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    company: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Company" },
}
```

**Company:**

```
( 
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    users : [{
        user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
        permistion: {type: Number, default: 0}
    }]
)
```

**1.** I want to find the user with `permistion = 1` in Company.

**2.** I want to find the user and result user: `{name, company, permistionCompany}`

I have alrealy fix this problem. The contruction of my model is so bad and I fix my model:

**User:**

```
{ 
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    company: {
        id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Company" },
        userPermission: { type: Number, default: 0}
    },
```

**Company:**

```
( 
    name: { type: String, required: true},
    users : [{user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User"}],
)
```

And when I want to find user in this company and permistion = 1, I just use:

```
User.find({_id: userId, company.id: companyId, company.userPermistion: 1})
```

Comment: Show us what you tried that isn't working as expected after doing your initial research. The objective here is to help you fix your attempts to solve the issue...not to write the code for you or to be a *"how to"* tutorial service

Answer (score 0):

1) Two ways you can query inside an array. You can use $elemMatch (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) or, given the structure of the schema, you can just do:

```
Company.find({"users.permistion": 1}, (error, docs) => {
  console.log(docs)  
})
```

2) Not quite understanding the question, but going to assume you want to get the information from your 'Users' collection given the query above. If that's the case, you can do a .populate. A good guide would be here: https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7

```
Company.find({"users.permistion": 1}).populate("users.user", (error, docs) => {
    console.log(docs)  
})
```